# Filter two lengthy paired lists of data

Tags: python, list, filter, runtime, simultaneous

I have a list of time data, with each value being a datetime value.
I have a list of measurements that are floats to go along with the time data, i.e. measurement[i] occurred at time[i].

Some measurements are not floats, and are empty strings.

I want to filter out all measurements that are empty strings, and equivalently filter out the times that are associated with these measurements.

The time and measurement lists are quite lengthy, so it would be great to factor in runtime into a solution for this problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with *list comprehension* expression to filter the values. For example, let's say the value of your lists are:

```
# For demo purpose
>>> measurement = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', '']
>>> time        = [  1,   2,  3,   4,  5]
```

Below expression will filter the item from both lists if value is `''` in `measurement` list.

```
>>> measurement, time = zip(*[(i, j) for i, j in zip(measurement, time) if i !=''])
```

Final values hold by your `measurement` and `time` list will be:

```
>>> measurement
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> time
(1, 2, 4)
```

Comment: since performance is a concern, using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and `filter`.  Here I unzip the two lists again, but you don't have to.

```
from numbers import Number
time, measurement = zip(*filter(lambda x: isinstance(x[1], Number), zip(time, measurement)))
```